# Can I use manifests to consume a COM server without specifying its version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, com, manifest, side-by-side

Two of our programs use the same COM server (also made by us) with the same class ids. Each program when installing copies the COM server files into its folder and `regsvr32`s the COM server.

The problem is how to install the COM server so that the user can install either one or both of our programs into different folders in any order and likely of different versions. Clearly it's impossible without changing the class ids and that's lots of hassle with configurations. Ideally we would like to use manifests for that and go without `regsvr32`.

The problem is every time I read about reg-free COM (for example, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)) there's the `version` attribute in the `assemblyIdentity`. The version number should change every nightly build and I totally don't like the idea of (automatically) adjusting it. I understand why specifying dependency on a specific version is good, but it's completely useless in our scenarion.

Is there a way to write manifests for both the COM server and the consumer so that they don't specify versions and just work with whatever version of the file happens to be in the folder? Also is there a way to restrict the search to the same folder as the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Windows searches for manifests only in the [global location followed by the application directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374224%28VS.85%29.aspx). If you don't install anything globally, search is effectively restricted to the same folder.

If you're always shipping the COM server in the same folder as the COM client, they are effectively one "software unit". `version` considerations are interface contracts between different software units, so in your scenario it doesn't matter. You can either omit the version attribute from the identity or set it to something fixed like "1.0.0.0", knowing that at that point, it's up to the way you distribute the software to ensure the proper versioning story, and not the side-by-side system.